# Does the Windows Phone Internet Explorer Mobile 7 browser support touch events?

Tags: javascript, browser, windows-phone-7, touch

Android and iPhone support touchstart, touchmove, touchend, and touchcancel.  Does the Windows Phone Internet Explorer Mobile 7 browser support these events or any analogous events?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. These events are not currently supported in IE7 Mobile.

You can get `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` and `MouseUp` though. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/7d532167-c26d-472f-8994-346f8fc9f840 for an example